# How Can I change the way that focus looks like in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, focus

The focus visual hint that wpf provides on Windows 7 is a dashed line, as such this:
[image: FocusExample]

Now, how can I change the way it looks? How can I control its appearence?

Thanks!

Comment: Inherit the control your using their.  When the button is selected redraw the button how you want it to appear.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try something like following

```
<Window x:Class="FocusVisualStyle.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyFocusVisualStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="-2" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Red"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="24">
    <TextBox Width="96"/>
    <Button Content="Yes" Width="64" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisualStyle}"/>
    <Button Content="No" Width="64" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisualStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You can customise to suit your liking. This is just a starting point.

Edit: Since so many people have liked this solution here is **another example which changes focus visual style for all buttons and textboxes without explicit setting of FocusVisualStyle property for each control (see that DynamicResource thingy?) in xaml**

Also it uses animation to change the colour of the focus rectangle.

Enjoy :)

```
<Window x:Class="FocusVisualStyle.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyFocusVisualStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate >
                    <Rectangle Margin="-2" StrokeThickness="2" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" >
                        <Rectangle.Stroke>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Name="RectangleStroke" />
                        </Rectangle.Stroke>
                        <Rectangle.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded" >
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation From="Red"
                                                        To="Orange"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.5" 
                                                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleStroke"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation To="3" 
                                                         Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                         RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Rectangle.Triggers>
                    </Rectangle>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyFocusVisualStyle}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyFocusVisualStyle}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="24">
    <TextBox Width="96"/>
    <Button Content="Yes" Width="64" />
    <Button Content="No" Width="64" />
</StackPanel>
```

Here you see that I have styles for Button and TextBox which set the property FocusVisualStyle for all the buttons and text boxes in this window.

Comment: Your style is triggered only on keyboard focus but not mouse focus

Comment: I'll check it out, it's been quite a while since I posted it. Will come back as soon as I can.

Comment: @user841612, that's because `FocusVisualStyle` only is employed when the focus is gained through keyboard, not programatically or using the mouse.

Comment: A custom action (derived from TriggerAction) is what was needed but I never got a chance to work on my machine at home and write some code. Also that would be out of scope for this question.