# Change the focus color on button when pressing tab on it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have button with a black background. When you **tab to the Button**, you don't see that focus is now on the Button because of the Button's background color. How can I change the focus frame to be red?

(When you have focus on the Button, you see some frame with points in the button)

```
<Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
         ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
         Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
         ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
         Focusable="False"/>
</Border>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
         </Trigger>

....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Can I change the way that focus looks like in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996248/how-can-i-change-the-way-that-focus-looks-like-in-wpf)

Comment: See your comment now, deleting answer.

Comment: @outflak, my comment wasn't here when you posted your answer. It was *your* answer that pointed out the duplicate post, so after reading your answer and seeing the duplicate post that *you* linked to, I voted to close this question as a duplicate. My point is that when you know that a question has been duplicated on Stack Overflow, you're *not* suppose to provide an answer pointing to it. Instead, you should leave a comment similar to the one I left above, or vote to close the question if/once you have enough reputation. Many thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Got it. You could have said that instead of down voting my answer though. That protocol sounds absolutely reasonable. I've just never seen it enforced. I'll look into the closing-of-questions philosophy of Stackoverflow. ...If anybody is interested, the link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="Control">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                 <Rectangle x:Name="bd" Stroke="Red" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashCap="Triangle" StrokeDashArray="1,2" Margin="1" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Margin" Value="1"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>                                
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
<Button Content="Hello World" Background="Gray" Height="35" Width="200" ></Button>
```

**Update**

As per my Knowledge Elements that are not enabled do not participate in hit testing or focus and therefore will not be sources of input events.so one has to use workaround like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisualStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="bd" Stroke="Red" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashCap="Triangle" StrokeDashArray="1,2" Margin="1" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="Buttonstyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource FocusVisualStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Focusable="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1"  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Margin" Value="1"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="gd"  Height="35" Width="200">
    <Grid.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Grid">
              <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=bt,Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                       <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"></Setter>
                       <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource FocusVisualStyle}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
     </Grid.Style>
     <Button x:Name="bt" IsEnabled="False" Style="{StaticResource Buttonstyle}" Content="Hello World"   IsTabStop="True"  Background="Gray"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Voted up ,just one last question when the button is dissable i have some opacity like 0.3 ,and when the tab is in this button you dont see the red coloer,how should I overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IsFocused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.uielement.isfocused%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) dependency property in your triggers. I suggest you to change the border width, or its colour, to differentiate the button from the unfocused ones. The dashed rectangle that indicates focus is, as far as I know, implemented in the built controls only. If you make a template, you should override it to suit your needs.

Comment: HI Oscar,can you please provide example ?