# How to use different image as content in button style?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, windows-store-apps, styles

I am working on window store app development. I have a button, it uses style defined as this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="ms-appx:///image1.png"/>
</Style>
```

Can I make it work so if my button is focused, I could show image2.png instead of image1.png? I am working on window store app, so a trigger is not supported here. Shall I use Visual state manager here?

Comment: May I know why it is down voted so I can avoid problem next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, I see that you have two requirements, one requirement is to set the Image as the content of the Button, the other requirement is to change the Button's content to another image when the Button gets focused.

**Requirement 1: Setting the Image as the content of the Button**

I see that you have used the following style to set the image as a content of the Button:

Using your code directly can not set the image as the content of Button, in order to implement it we need to put the Image control in the Button's template.

**PS: Since you are using the Windows Store app, I will ues the Windows 8.1 store app as example for my later information, it will be almost same for the UWP app.**

We can get the Button's Template by creating a Button in XAML and right click the Button control-->"Edit Template"-->"Edit a Copy..." as following:

[image]

Then it will show us the default style of the Button control with the Name:**OriginalButtonStyle**, after that please find **ContentPresenter** and add the Image control inside it as following:

```
  <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
       <Image Name="MyImage" Source="{TemplateBinding Content}"></Image>
  </ContentPresenter>
```

After that if we set the Content of the Button as a value of the ImageURL/Soruce for example:**ms-appx:///image1.png**, it will show the Image as the Content of the Button.

**Requirement 2: Changing the Button's content to another image when the Button gets focused.**

Please find the these **PointerOver Pressed Focused PointerFocused** VisualState and add the following XAML one by one, because these visualstates will be fired when the Button goes into the focused state:

```
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="MyImage">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="ms-appx:///image2.png "/>
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

So the whole style: **OriginalButtonStyle** for the Button will be following:

```
       <Style x:Key="OriginalButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="MyImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="ms-appx:///image1.png"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="MyImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="ms-appx:///image1.png"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="MyImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="ms-appx:///image1.png"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source" Storyboard.TargetName="MyImage">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="ms-appx:///image1.png"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Image Name="MyImage" Source="{TemplateBinding Content}"></Image>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="0.5" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Note:**
All above changes are made in the **OriginalButtonStyle**, in order to use your **MyButtonStyle**, we can **inherit** the **MyButtonStyle** from the **OriginalButtonStyle** as following:

```
  <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource OriginalButtonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="ms-appx:///image1.png"/>
    </Style>


<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="button" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,100,100,100" />
</Grid>
```

After that it works fine.

Fore more information, please check: [Button styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to set the FocusVisualStyle, refer to this answer for an example: [How Can I change the way that focus looks like in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996248/how-can-i-change-the-way-that-focus-looks-like-in-wpf)