# How to customize textbox and combo box border WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox, textbox, styles, border

Before I post my code let me post image where you can easily notice what's acctually happening:

[image]

And as you can see on text boxes, border thickness is not same on every side.
In case of textbox it is much more brighter on the right for example.
Also on combobox there is something like shadow on top and on left side..

How could I fix this, I simply want 1px blue border around my controls..

And here is my code:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbComboBoxOne"  Height="40" BorderThickness="1"   VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#0091EA" ></ComboBox>
<TextBox Name="txtTextBoxOne"    TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="TextBox" BorderThickness="1"        BorderBrush="#0091EA" />
```

**EDIT:**

I applied Edit Template Copy, I set border thickness to 1 and colour to purple, and it looks like this:

[image]

So guys, again it is not good with thickness:1 px, for example with thickness:2px its awesome, all sides are equal but 2px is too much for me..

Here is my code after I edited template:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Column="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Height="40"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle1}"  >
            <TextBox.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Purple"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
                    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ClassicBorderDecorator x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderStyle="Sunken" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                                </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ClassicBorderDecorator>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Resources>
        </TextBox>
```

as you can see guys

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Purple"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
```

are set, but result is somehow same :/

Comment: WPF layout is floating point, not integer. Play with SnapToDevicePixels and UseLayoutRounding

Comment: @EdPlunkett first time I hear about that mate, how I could implement it here? Could you provide me example? Thanks a lot Ed

Comment: They're properties of XAML elements. `<ComboBox SnapToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"`. However it is *much better* to set them on a parent than on every single element, since they're inherited. You don't want to clutter up your XAML with massively redundant attributes like that (well, lots of people do, actually, for whatever reason -- but don't).

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks mate, I applied that, but unfortunately that did not help me, after that I Edited templated but that also did not help me, check for EDIT of my question :/

Comment: Your before and after screenshots look very different to me. They look exactly like I would expect. Note btw that a focused control may have [`FocusVisualStyle` interfering with the regular template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996248/how-can-i-change-the-way-that-focus-looks-like-in-wpf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the SnapsToDevicePixels and/or UseLayoutRounding properties to True:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbComboBoxOne" ... SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True" />
```

If this doesn't work you could try to modify the control template of the controls. Right-click on them in design mode in Visual Studio 2012+ or Blend and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy to copy the default templates into your XAML markup and then set the above properties on the Border elements in the generated templates.

**Edit:** Replace the ClassicBorderDecorator with an ordinary Border element:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtName" Grid.Column="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,10,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Height="40"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxStyle1}"  >
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Purple"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: check for EDIT of my question

Comment: It works mate, but is it possible to Edit this template copy only once and to apply it on all textboxes? because if we follow this example for 10 textboxes, it will be like 100 lines of code, that's bit too much :D Thanks a lot mate!! :* :* :* :* :*

Comment: Yes, you could for example put the <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">...</Style> inside <Application.Resources> in your App.xaml and apply the global style to any TextBox in your application using the StaticResource markup extension: <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" />

Comment: I did it and it works as expected. I am wondering now, is it possible to do the same for combo boxes? they also looks really sucks :)

Comment: It's the same. Copy the default style of the ComboBox into your App.xaml and edit it as per your requirements. I am not sure exactly how the default template looks like on Windows 7 but look for something similar to the ClassicBorderDecorator element in the template and replace it with an ordinary Border element that you set the SnapsToDevicePixels property of to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize textbox and combobox border you need to change default style and template of these controls by right click on control and select edit template.