# How to trigger FocusVisualStyle by clicking on a button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here are my questions :

- Is it possible to trigger a FocusVisualStyle when the click event of a button occurs ?
- Is it possible to make a button do not have any FocusVisualStyle ?

**I just found a kind of answer to the second question.**

I assigned a new FocusVisualStyle to the button as below, and I deleted the Rectangle Control in ControlTemplate so that ControlTemplate is now empty.

I will greatly appreciate your help if you have a better way to do it or if you can answer the first question.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyFocusVisualStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="-2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisualStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I change the way that focus looks like in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996248/how-can-i-change-the-way-that-focus-looks-like-in-wpf)

Comment: Thank you, I examined the discussions on this link and completely rephrased my question because I found some answers. - @ASh